# Computing the intersection of two big lists is not fast enough

Tags: python, performance

```
import random
import string

LENGTH = 5
LIST_SIZE = 1000000

def generate_word():
    word = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(LENGTH)]
    word = ''.join(word)
    return word

list1 = [generate_word() for _ in range(LIST_SIZE)]
list2 = [generate_word() for _ in range(LIST_SIZE)]

intersection = [word for word in list1 if word in list2]
print(len(intersection))
```

I have two big lists and I try to find out how many items they have in common. The code looks nice but is extremely slow. I computed that my PC can handle ~90M comparisons per sec. so the code would run for about 3 hours. A college of mine told me that the code can be significantly sped up.

Can you give me some tips how to make it faster?

Comment: This question is not as much a code review as a want for code rewrite. As such not entirely on topic. One suggestion could be to sort lists before checking, or use hash sets to speed up the lookup.

Comment: +1 for sets. They are the thing to use here.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues are -

**Don't store things in memory unless necessary**

In this line:

```
word = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(LENGTH)]
```

You're constructing a list in memory, which is bad for two reasons. First, a list is mutable, but you don't need the overhead of mutability, so you can use a tuple, which is slightly lighter. More importantly, this shouldn't land in memory at all. It should be stored as a generator, thus:

```
word = (random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(LENGTH))
```

**Try cStringIO instead of a join**

I don't have an interpreter in front of me, so I can't guarantee that this will help, but try replacing your generator + join with a simple loop that writes to an instance of cStringIO. Use `timeit` to evaluate your performance.

**Use sets**

Lists are absolutely not the right thing to use here. Call set thus:

```
list1 = set(generate_word() for _ in range(LIST_SIZE)) 
list2 = set(generate_word() for _ in range(LIST_SIZE)) 

intersection = list1 & list2
```

Comment: set does not take into account repetition within a list like in `list1 = [0,0,1]; list2 = [0,1, 2]`. OP is also not clear on what should happen in his explanation, but in his code, this should return 3

Comment: @MaartenFabré it's true, there is ambiguity. Even if he needs the repeated elements, `set` can still be used to speed up calculation of the intersection.

Comment: @MaartenFabré It was supposed to be a list of unique strings thus my code was not that well designed. But still the notes helped me and now the code runs about thousand times faster. Mindblowing! I would love to know where to learn these things so I don't have to bother people around everytime. You know, give a man a fish ... Writing code is easy. But writing good code is so difficult.

Comment: some good books are [whirlwind tour of Python](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/a-whirlwind-tour/9781492037859/) (free), [fluent python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do) and [effective python](https://effectivepython.com/)

Comment: @Reinderien Indeed. If repetition should be caught, `return sum(1 for word in list1 if word in set2)` can be effective too, or `sum(word in set2 for word in list1)`

Answer (score 2):

The `in` operator is very slow for large lists. You'd better have a look at 'high-performance container types' like [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).